# Getting the filename from a path in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string containing a filename and optionally can be a full path or a relative one.

`os.path` module seems to miss such function. What is the easiest solution?

Comment: What do you want to do with the string?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `os.path.basename`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the filename without the path, then use `basename`

```
from os.path import basename

# now you can call it directly with basename
print basename("/a/b/c.txt")
```

This will give `c.txt` as output.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : ( way to Go )

```
from os.path import basename
filename = basename("/home/user/file.txt")
```

Method 2 : ( Seems good but not a good method )

```
mypath = "/home/user/file.txt"
filename = mypath[mypath.rfind("/")+1:]
```

Method1 works in all cases, where as method2 will break often specially when moving platforms.
That is why we use `os`, that changes the underline logic with changing platforms, this is how python provides platform independence - Keeping the logic independent of os details.

Comment: using `basename` neglects all the path information.  This is useful only if you're trying to actually get the basename and not the Path.

Comment: That is what's desired above.